# iTunes App from Paid to Free - Existing User Dilemma

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I have an app in the iTunes Store and sales have slowed so want to convert it to a free app from a paid app. The new app will contain an option to buy, using In App Purchase. I was considering using a flag / pre processor macro to then allow full features for those that buy using the IAP, and limit features for those who have not.

The problem will be if I add this new pre processor macro to the new update, those who have previously paid for the app will not be able to use full features, as they would not have used the IAP to "unlock" the full app.

Does anyone have any suggestions to overcome this problem.

I have a few ideas, but in my mind they are not fool proof.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: please explain why that received a down vote???

Answer (score 1):

Pondering exactly the same issue here. The only thing i found workable (under most use cases) is to look-up gamestate information at when the new_free_iAP version starts.

If there is no iAP state, AND if games exist, AND the playtime counter > 0, i will make the assumption that the user bought this and will preseed his/her iAP configuration information to indicate that this was iPurchased. The only users left out would be buyers who NEVER started the app.

Not fool proof, but better than none. Ugly state to manage, nasty testing for this. And of course, this is a variable geometry solution : if I did not have reliable persisted state in the current version, i would not know where to start.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully there is an easier way.